# Адаптивная аутентификация

Tags: алгоритм, машинное-обучение, аутентификация

Добрый день

В университете в качестве курсовой работы - предложили сделать адаптивную аутентификацию.
например выявлять аномальные процедуры логина с не обычного ip адреса, гео локации, браузера, времени и.т.д.

Я решил сделать это с помощью байесового метода, но судя по всему не правильно делаю feature exctaction, потому что по формуле получается так:
всего записей пользователя в системе - 11

честный пользователь логинится например с ip 195.10.1.2, user agent: Chrome, Country: Belarus
записей для этого пользователя с таким ip - 10, с user agent - 10, с geo - 10, всего логинов - 10,
(10/10 * 10/10 * 10/10 * 10/11) = 0,9090909091

злоумышленник залогинился с 195.10.34.123, user agent: Chrome, Country: Belarus
записей для этого пользователя с таким ip - 1, с user agent - 10, с geo - 10, всего логинов - 1,
(10/1 * 1/1 * 1/1 * 1/11) = 9,090909091

т.е. злоумышленник, благодаря тому, что у него такой же user agent и всего 1 запись в системе - более честный пользователь

что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

У вас ошибка в формуле
Это не корректная классификация.

Вам необходимо считать сумму отдельно взятого признака.
IP + UA + GEO = X.X скоринг

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/250030)

Comment: поправил, уточнил